# ProLiant DL580 G7 E7 Upgrade Issue version 2

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, central-processing-unit

I am responsible for ProLiant DL580 upgrade to four E7-4870 processors.
We are running Windows Server 2012 R2.

The situation is very similar to what has already been discussed here:
[ProLiant DL580 G7 E7 Upgrade Issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/764327/proliant-dl580-g7-e7-upgrade-issue?newreg=bcc3c3c363f6412f9098be6ed375e8f8)

I face the same issue: if PROC3 is installed, the machine is not working.

1) PROC1=A, PROC2=C, PROC3=X, PROC4=B, POST=TRUE

2) PROC1=A, PROC2=C, PROC3=D, PROC4=B, POST=FALSE

A,B,C,D are E7-4870 (SLC3T) 130W TDP
X is empty socket

I live now with 3 new CPUs (30 physical cores) in position 1. I really need to install the fourth processor. I can not find any relevant installation files to update my CPLD chips. hp ftp server folders are empty now.

Do you have any ideas how to fix the problem? I am quite new to the topic but spent much time trying.

OS Name: MS Server 2012R2

Bios: HP P65, 16.08.2015

DL580 G7: 588857-B21

Memory Board: 588141-B21

iLO Firmware Version 1.05

Comment: Replace "hp" with "hpe" in any FTP URLs you may have.

Comment: @ewwhite Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this does not work. I did it for ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw/p2039955643/v85801. The result is "This site can’t be reached".  In the original question, Edgar1 gave this link for CPLD Linux update   (the folder is available but empty now).   I need it for WS 2012 R2, no ideas how to find the analog

Comment: I hope that @Edgar1, author of the [original post](https://serverfault.com/questions/764327/proliant-dl580-g7-e7-upgrade-issue?newreg=bcc3c3c363f6412f9098be6ed375e8f8) could give me a hand

Comment: Can you call HP?

Comment: Yes, they told the machine is old and they will not consult me.

Comment: Alexander: Have you checked the "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Downloads" web page for the "HP ProLiant DL580 G7 Server" - http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=4142793&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4168 - and particularly the "BIOS (Entitlement Required) - System ROM (3)" section? Maybe those downloads apply to your case (although I'm not entirely sure). I see that those "Downloads" do require that "An active warranty or support agreement covering Proliant servers must be linked to your HPE Support Center profile to access this BIOS." though :-/ Cc: @ewwhite

Comment: @ricmarques Yes, I have an access and the latest version of Bios. "HP P65, 16.08.2015" is already on board.

Comment: @AlexanderK: OK. That's good. But then I'm afraid that was all the help I'm able to give in this case :-( Good luck!

Comment: I'd suggest calling HP again.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you wandering in later, here's the bottom line:

You have main IO board 591196-001 rev 0A. That's the board with the PCI slots. The label over near the connectors to the CPU board says rev 0A. You need rev 0B.

The server will not post and boot if you have an E7 processor in slot 3 and the rev 0A main board installed. As soon as you remove processor 3 or install a rev 0B board, everything will work.